# Parallel conditional task process assignments

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

I'm building a rather large workflow in SPD 2013 that will route a document set to different individuals in the company depending on the criteria entered for the new document set. However, I'm coming across a logic issue.

For every document set, there are two conditions that can cause two more individuals to be added to the task assignment process. Originally, I had the WorkFlow broken into stages that would handle this sequentially, but now I need the task process to be handled simultaneously.

So ideally, the code would be:

```
If Cost > 5000
Then Start Task Process with these users
If Bond equals Yes
Then start task process with these users
If Engineering equals yes 
Then start task process with these users
```

However, doing this causes the workflow to become too big and refuses to publish. So in a nutshell, I need to be able to simultaneously assign tasks to all the conditional users, is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, everyone is doing the same task, just different people based on different conditions. If that's correct, then you should be able to use a workflow variable to gather the list of email addresses in a semi-colon separated list and then set assign the list to the task process.

Sudocode would look something like:

If Cost > 5000
Set Variable Userlist to: [%Variable: USERLIST%]; [Userlookup/Return Email]
If Bond equals Yes
Set Variable Userlist to: [%Variable: USERLIST%]; [Userlookup/Return Email]
If Engineering equals yes
Set Variable Userlist to: [%Variable: USERLIST%]; [Userlookup/Return Email]

**Note the semicolons, use the builder rather than define lookup.

Then start task process with [these users]

In the these users dialog for participants, do a workflow lookup, USERLIST, return as Email Addresses, Semicolon Delimitated.

Comment: This is genius.

Comment: Thank you so much, literally have been bashing my head about this.